# Getting width and height from loaded bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to get the width and height of an image, which I load from an image I pick from the gallery.
For testing, I used images from the drawable folder, I used this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

Now I got a bitmap that doesn't come from my drawable folder I can't do this:

```
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
```

What would be the proper way to retrieve the w/h.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar method working with an InputStream: [BitmapFactory.decodeStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)).

Assuming you have a File with your image (exceptions ommitted)  :

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(myImageFile), null, options);
```

(this method works for any InputStream)